# ACF plugin - Wordpress: Not saving sets of sub fields in a repeater when I have several sets (about >150)

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a Wordpress site and I'm using the ACF plugin. In one of my posts I have a repeater field with a lot of sets of sub fields. I have a problem when I have a lot of these sets (about 150) in a post and I try to update the post adding more sets. Some times the post remains equals, without the new sets. And some times some sets (not the new ones) are removed from the post and the new sets are not saved.

I've made some changes on my server through php.ini, but the problem still remains:

```
max_input_vars = 3000
max_input_nesting_level = 128
max_input_time = 300
max_execution_time = 150
post_max_size = 32M
```

Any idea on how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it.

I had the php.ini in the root folder. I just moved it to the wp-admin folder and it works. If the php.ini is in the root folder, the changes in php.ini aren't applied to the Wordpress Back-End.